# How to dynamically generate and display a certain background on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JFrame and it has a JPanel. In my JPanel class, I have some combo-boxes, and a button. What I would like to do is dynamically switch (I suppose repaint() - am I right?) my JPanel is based on those combo-boxes and button. So simply creating two panels and making one opaque or whatever, won't work. I would really appreciate if someone provided me with some guidance. I would like to do this in the simplest way possible. I would also like all buttons/combo-boxes and whatever else to carry over into this new background.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just to call setBackground(Color):
Example:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I believe that only dispays colors, while I'd like to display something more complex.

Comment: what do you mean by more complex?

Comment: Like lets say I wanted to zoom in on an image, or draw custom shapes on something based on certain parameters. I'm sorry if these things are implemented in drastically different ways, seeing as I have no idea how to do either, they are essentially equivalent in my mind.

Comment: @user2574476: Zooming on an image and drawing custom shapes are two different Swing applications, and require a different coding approach.  Take a look at this [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) to see how to start a drawing Swing application.