# Java JFrame Opens too small

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to create PingPong in java, however I am having troubles creating boundaries for the ball. After testing, I found that the JFrame opens too small; I set the width to 500 and the JFrame opens at 484 pixels. Why is this?

Here is my game class:

public class Game extends Canvas {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Game();
}

Display d;


public Game(){
    d = new Display(this);
    requestFocus();
}


public void start(){
    System.out.println("Game started.");
}
public void stop(){

}


public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawLine(483, 0, 483, 399);
    g.drawLine(0, 399, 499, 399);
}
```

}

Here is my JFrame class:

public class Display extends JFrame {

```
JFrame frame;
Dimension screenSize;

public Display(Game game){
    frame = new JFrame("PingPong");
    screenSize = new Dimension(500, 400);



    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    //frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
    frame.setMinimumSize(screenSize);
    frame.setMaximumSize(screenSize);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    //frame.pack();
    game.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `setSize` on a `JFrame`, it includes the size of the title bar, as well as any other decoration around the window. So the actual drawable area you have is going to be a bit less than that. You can work around this by setting your `Game`'s preferred size, and using `pack` on the `JFrame`.

So if you change your code to this:

```
public Display(Game game){
    super("PingPong");
    screenSize = new Dimension(500, 400);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    game.setPreferredSize(screenSize);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add(game);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    game.start();
}
```

It will work. This tells your actual game what size it wants to be (500x400), and then has the frame resize so that it can fully contain it. That will give you 500x400 pixels to work with in your actual drawing.

Notice that I removed all the `frame` references. Since `Display` itself is already a `JFrame` you don't need to create another one. Just use the `Display` object itself.

Comment: How exactly would I do this? I am fairly new to game development in java

Comment: @Lol: Take a look at this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35002727/300257).  It's not ping-pong, but it shows you how to draw properly in Java Swing.  Also, take a look at Oracle's [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to see another example.

Comment: @Lol It's pretty easy. Looking at your code, I see that you actually had it pretty close. You just need to change `frame.setPreferredSize(screenSize)` to `game.setPreferredSize(screenSize)`, comment out the `setMinimumSize` and `setMaximumSize` lines, and uncomment `frame.pack()`. I'll add what it will look like to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `frame.pack()` then it will work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.