# Background image in different place every time

Tags: java

I have a large program that I will post some classes of and hopefully you guys can find the problem. Basically, sometimes when I start it, it creates the game just fine, and others the background is up a few pixels to the north and west directions leaving very unsightly whitespace. I cannot seem to find the missing piece of code that decides whether not it does this. It honestly feel like some kind of rendering glitch on my machine. At any rate, I have put a background `getX` and `getY` method in for debugging and have noticed that whether the background is fully stretched to the screen(its a custom background so the pixel height and width match perfectly), or its up and to the left, the background still reads that it is displaying at (0,0). I will post all the methods from the main thread to the creating of the background in the menu. I will leave notes indicating the path it takes through this code that gets it to creating the background. Thank you for your help and I will check in regularly for edits and more information.

EDIT: added background.java
EDIT2: added pictures explaining problem

Menu.java *ignore the `FileIO` code, the main point is the creation of a new GamePanel()

```
    public class Menu {

    private static File file;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        file = new File("saves.txt");
        if(file.exists()){
            FileIO.run();
            FileIO.profileChoose();
        }
        else{
            FileIO.profileCreate();
            FileIO.run();
        }

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Jolly Jackpot Land");
        window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Next is the GamePanel.java

```
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {
    // ID
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Dimensions
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    // Thread
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 30;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

    // Image
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    // Game State Manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;

    public GamePanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    private void init() {
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        running = true;

        gsm = new GameStateManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        // Game Loop
        while (running) {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            wait = targetTime - (elapsed / 1000000);

            if (wait < 0) {
                wait = 5;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        gsm.update();
    }

    private void draw() {
        gsm.draw(g);
    }

    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        gsm.keyPressed(k.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

This calls for the creation of a new `GameStateManager` object in its `init()` method and the class for that is here.

GameStateManager.java

```
public class GameStateManager {


    private ArrayList<GameState> gameStates;
    private int currentState;

    public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
    public static final int SLOTGAMESTATE = 1;
    public static final int DICEGAMESTATE = 2;
    public static final int ROULETTEGAMESTATE = 3;
    public static final int LEADERBOARDSTATE = 4;
    public static final int SETTINGSSTATE = 5;
    public static final int HELPSTATE = 6;


    public GameStateManager() {
        gameStates = new ArrayList<GameState>();

        currentState = 0;
        gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));
        gameStates.add(new SlotGameState(this));
        gameStates.add(new DiceGameState(this));
        gameStates.add(new RouletteGameState(this));
        gameStates.add(new LeaderboardState(this));
        gameStates.add(new SettingsState(this));
        gameStates.add(new HelpState(this));


    }

    public void setState(int state){
        currentState = state;
        gameStates.get(currentState).init();
        currentState = 0;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    public void update() {
        gameStates.get(currentState).init();
    }

    public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g){
        gameStates.get(currentState).draw(g);
    }

    public void keyPressed(int k){
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
    }

    public void keyReleased(int k) {
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
    }
}
```

`GameState` is an abstract class I have so its not worth posting, it only contains `init()`, `draw()`, etc. This next class is the last and final class and is called because `GameStateMananger` starts at `MENUSTATE` or 0, and when GSM is initialized it initializes its current state, thus taking us to the class `MenuState`

MenuState.java

```
public class MenuState extends GameState {

    private Background bg;

    public FontMetrics fontMetrics;

    private int choice = 0;
    private String[] options = { "Slot Machine", "Dice Toss", "Roulette Wheel", "Leaderboards", "Settings", "Help",
            "Quit" };

    private Color titleColor;
    private Font titleFont;

    private Font font;

    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        this.gsm = gsm;
        try {
            bg = new Background("/Backgrounds/happybg.png");

            titleColor = Color.WHITE;
            titleFont = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 28);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        fontMetrics = c.getFontMetrics(font);
        // Draw BG
        bg.draw(g);

        // Draw title
        g.setColor(titleColor);
        g.setFont(titleFont);
        String title = "Jolly Jackpot Land!";
        g.drawString(title, 36, 60);

        g.setFont(font);

        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (i == choice)
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            else
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(options[i], 30, 120 + i * 15);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        g.drawString("v1.1", 165, 235);

        Object[] a = { ("Name: " + Player.getName()), ("Gil: " + Player.getGil()),
                ("Personal Best: " + Player.getPersonalBest()), ("Winnings: " + Player.getWinnings()),
                ("Wins: " + Player.getWins()), ("Losses: " + Player.getLosses()),
                ("Win/Loss Ratio: " + String.format("%.2f", Player.getRatio()) + "%") };

        g.setFont(font);

        if (Player.getName() != null) {
            for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
                g.drawString(a[x].toString(), GamePanel.WIDTH - fontMetrics.stringWidth(a[x].toString()) - 30,
                        120 + x * 15);
            }
        }
    }

    private void select() {
        if (choice == 0) {
            // Slots
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.SLOTGAMESTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            // Dice
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.DICEGAMESTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            // Roulette
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.ROULETTEGAMESTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            // Leaderboards
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEADERBOARDSTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 4) {
            // Settings
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.SETTINGSSTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 5) {
            // Help
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.HELPSTATE);
        }
        if (choice == 6) {
            // Quit
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            select();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            choice--;
            if (choice == -1) {
                choice = options.length - 1;
            }
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            choice++;
            if (choice == options.length) {
                choice = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(int k) {
    }
}
```

Background.java

```
public class Background {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Background(String s) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

This is where it waits for input in the game loop basically. I know this is a lot of code, but a lot of it is skimming till a method call takes you to the next class. I just can't figure out why it only happens sometimes, if it was consistent I could debug it. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

[image: running the code]
[image: running it again, but different result]

These are both from clicking the .jar of the above program, exact same .jar, exact same source code, different result. I am bewildered.

Comment: Should we start with how `getGraphics` is NOT how custom painting is done in Swing, you're basically running the risk a race condition between you code painting the onto the `Graphics` context and Swing doing the same, which will result in flickering occuring. If you require active control over the painting process then you should be using [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), see also [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details

Comment: Also, don't dispose of a `Graphics` context you didn't create yourself, this can cause some systems to stop painting

Comment: There's no need to create a `Canvas` in you `draw` method `Graphics2D` has a `getFontMetrics` method of its own.  How does the `Background` class draw it self?

Comment: Take a look at this [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) to see how a simple Swing application with graphics is supposed to be coded.