# Adding another movable image in Swing

Tags: swing

I have stumpled upon a problem. What I'm trying to do is to add another movable image in JPanel, movable as in that one could drag it with the mouse. This program only can view one image at the time and drag it arround. So how could I do to have more than one picture in my program?
=)

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
public class test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test2();
}

public test2() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            Bild bild = new Bild();
            frame.add(new DragMyIcon("katt.gif"));
            frame.setSize(640,460);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
   });
}

protected class DragMyIcon extends JPanel {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 172L;
    private JLabel label;

    public DragMyIcon(String path) {
        setLayout(null);
        ImageIcon icon = null;
        icon = new ImageIcon(path);
        label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.setBounds(0,0,icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        setBounds(0,0,icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label);

        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        label.addMouseListener(handler);
        label.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }
}

protected class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private boolean active = false;
    private int xDisp;
    private int yDisp;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        active = true;
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
        xDisp = e.getPoint().x - label.getLocation().x;
        yDisp = e.getPoint().y - label.getLocation().y;
        label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        active = false;
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
        label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (active) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
            Point point = e.getPoint();
            label.setLocation(point.x - xDisp, point.y - yDisp);
            label.invalidate();
            label.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}}
```

Comment: Instead of using a JLabel to hold the image, create a drawing panel from a JPanel and draw the images directly on the drawing panel.  Here's one example from a [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727).

Comment: @Dennis Borgström I don't see a problem here. Why don't just add another label and add your MouseHandler to it? Have you tried that?

Comment: Don't add the `MouseListener` to the labels instead add them to the container of the labels, you will then need to ascertain if the `MouseEvent` occured on a given component or not, but the solution is far more scalable

Comment: Add the MouseListener to the label (like you are currently doing) then you don't need to write your own code to determine which component the mouse was clicked on. This way you only add the listener to the components you want to drag. You can also create a reusable class to do something like this so you don't have to keep writing custom code every time you want to do dragging. For example check out the `ComponentMover` example from [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). Or you can just use the basic dragging class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do is to add another movable image in JPanel,

Where? I don't see any code?

You only add a single label to the panel. If you want to drag more than one then you need to add more than one label to the panel.

> This program only can view one image at the time and drag it arround.

Well maybe you need a method like `addImage(Image image, int x, int y)`. Then when you invoke this method you:

1. create a JLabel using the image for the Icon
2. set the bounds of the label using the x/y and the image size
3. add the listeners to the label
4. add the label to the panel