# How to draw a shape

Tags: java, jpanel

I am new to using the paint component and wondering why it isn't appearing in my graphArea (jpanel). I have the class drawpanel which is implementing it but it is not providing me with any errors. Am i meant to add something else to allow the oval to display??

```
public class graphGUI extends JFrame { 

    JFileChooser fc;

    //private final JTextArea graphArea = new JTextArea();
    private final JPanel graphArea = new JPanel();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `graphArea.paintComponents(g);` ? You are calling a paint method of a `JPanel` from another `JPanel` .

Comment: @Berger I thought thats how I would add it to the graphArea panel in my gui?

Comment: Here's an [example Java Swing GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) that shows you how to create as proper paintComponent method.  You paint in the paintComponent method.  Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed things up, you probably want `graphArea` to be a `DrawPanel`, so :

```
private final JPanel graphArea = new DrawPanel();
```

Then in `paintComponent`, remove you last call because it has no use, but call the parent's method instead, to let it do its painting first.

```
     @Override 

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)    {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it isnt accepting the code ive added above? im trying to display a graph from an object. its complaining about the the JPanel in the paramaters, saying it cant find the symbol. but obviously its not a variable