# java MVC , multiple listeners

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listeners

I am new to GUI programming with java and some questions occured in my head. I am learning now the MVC-pattern and I was wondering how the implementation of a JFrame with a button to create squares on click would look like .
What I want to do is : I have a Frame and a button, the button is pressed and a new square is randomly positioned on the screen, then i can drag it around in the frame and change its position and the console has an output : Square1 was moved to X Y  (coordinates);
Then ,if the button is pressed again, a new square is created (Square2). When I drag it, the console says : Square2 was moved to X Y .

Any suggestions what I should do in order to make that possible ? 
I know that my model is actually the square and its properties.My view is actually the JFrame with the button. But I do not know how to implement the controller, so that I can get the console outputs for the different objects..

Thank you !

Comment: You've asked a very broad question (in fact I think you've asked more than one). Basically, you need a model which would maintain information about each rectangle, this model would need to have the ability to change the the properties of each rectangle. You would have a view which would draw the rectangles and allow the user to drag them to a new position, at which time the model would need to be updated. You would then need a controller to bind the view and model together. You would need another view to contain the button and a controller to manage it, they could actually use the same model

Comment: Because Swing is already a form of MVC, trying to wrap it again in another MVC is problematic, I tend to work on the principle of the view been an isolated element which has a specified contract that the controller can work with, but that's me

Comment: This [Swing GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) is different than what you want to do, but implements the model / view / controller pattern.  You can use this Swing GUI as a starting point for your Swing GUI

Answer (score 0):

**quick answer :**

**" your main method in your java class can be act as your controller.
 views are pages but you're using swing components instead, so it's your view in this case. "**