# Shapes appear for a moment and then disappear

Tags: java, canvas, graphics

I was trying to draw simple shapes on a canvas in java (using Eclipse). The canvas appears of the right size and color. The shapes however appear only for a second and then disappear. When they appear they have the correct size, color and location, but they disappear after a second or so. It seems that a line is missing from the below code I wrote, but I can't figure out what it is.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.*;

    /**
     * Draws simple shapes
     */


public class SimpleDraw2 {
    private JFrame frame;
    private static Canvas canvas;
    private Container contentPane;
    private static Graphics graphics;
    private Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Creates canvas and frame
     */
    public SimpleDraw2() {
        frame = new JFrame("Draw picture");
        contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(250, 250);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }//end constructor

    /**
     * Draws two circles
     * @param g
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(125, 125, 50, 50);
        g = canvas.getGraphics();
        if(g != null){
            ((Graphics2D) g).fill(circle);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
        }
    }//end method

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDraw2 draw = new SimpleDraw2();
        draw.paint(graphics);
    }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Canvas class.  You should draw on a JPanel.  [Moving Eyes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) is a simple example of a Swing drawing program.

Comment: "You shouldn't be using the Canvas class": because you just thought of it??

Answer (score -1):

Ah... in the SimpleDraw2.paint() method you get the canvas and then call its paint() method.
You should not do that. Ignore SimpleDraw2.paint() and instead post your paint code inside the canvas.paint() method. This way it will get drawn properly.

Painintg to canvas inside SimpleDraw2.paint() will in fact draw to the canvas, but as soon as that repaints itself, all shapes will be cleared.

Btw dont call paint(Graphics) directly, as you do it in the main() method, rather call repaint()

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your answer! Are you saying that although SimpleDraw2.paint method does not call canvas.paint() method, it will somehow be called automatically? How do I put my code into canvas.paint method? Should I made SimpleDraw2 class an extension of Canvas?

Answer (score -1):

**[UPDATED]**

Oh almost forgot... usually you should put your code into the paintComponent() method. See the four test classes.

In v1, the canvas object you create is drawn above the paintings. I don't exactly know what content pane drawing changes in the drawing cycle, along with painting child components, and/or layout managers. That might be one of the reasons why, even though we don't call super.paint(), the canvas still gets painted.

V2 (and v4) gives you maximum control over your paint cycle, and using double/multiple buffering gets a lot easier this way.

V3 is easiest, just straight painting to the main frame, not having any variables or special magic.

In v4, you can also interface that callback(s). Gives you good control and is quite simple too.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;



public class GraphicsPaint {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SimpleDraw2v1();
        new SimpleDraw2v2();
        new SimpleDraw2v3();
        new SimpleDraw2v4();
    }
}



class SimpleDraw2v1 {
    private final JFrame        frame;
    private static Canvas       canvas;
    private final Container     contentPane;
    private static Graphics     graphics;
    private Ellipse2D.Double    circle;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Creates canvas and frame
     */
    public SimpleDraw2v1() {
        frame = new JFrame("Draw picture");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // important
        contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(250, 250);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }//end constructor

    /**
     * Draws two circles
     * @param g
     */
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(125, 125, 50, 50);

        final Graphics2D g2 = ((Graphics2D) g);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }//end method

}//end class



class SimpleDraw2v2 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2057752114790427629L;

    public SimpleDraw2v2() {
        setTitle("Painting v2");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new MyDrawPanel());
        setBounds(200, 200, 800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}



class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6483380689207640805L;

    @Override public void paint(final Graphics pG) {
        // this call (or not overwriting paint() in the first place) results in
        super.paint(pG);

        // these three calls, in this order. you can test it
        //      paintComponent(pG);
        //      paintBorder(pG);
        //      paintChildren(pG);

        final Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(125, 125, 50, 50);

        final Graphics2D g2 = ((Graphics2D) pG);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
    @Override protected void paintComponent(final Graphics pG) {
        System.out.println("MyDrawPanel.paintComponent()");
        super.paintComponent(pG);
    }
    @Override protected void paintBorder(final Graphics pG) {
        System.out.println("MyDrawPanel.paintBorder()");
        super.paintBorder(pG);
    }
    @Override protected void paintChildren(final Graphics pG) {
        System.out.println("MyDrawPanel.paintChildren()");
        super.paintChildren(pG);
    }
}



class SimpleDraw2v3 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2057752114790427629L;

    public SimpleDraw2v3() {
        setTitle("Painting v3");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(200, 200, 800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override public void paint(final Graphics pG) {
        super.paint(pG);

        final Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(125, 125, 50, 50);
        final Graphics2D g2 = ((Graphics2D) pG);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}



class SimpleDraw2v4 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2057752114790427629L;

    public SimpleDraw2v4() {
        setTitle("Painting v4");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8011251549484904282L;

            @Override public void paint(final Graphics pG) {
                super.paint(pG);
                paintShapes((Graphics2D) pG); // use this call
            }
            @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics pG) {
                super.paintComponent(pG);
                paintShapes((Graphics2D) pG); // or this call
            }
        });
        setBounds(200, 200, 800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void paintShapes(final Graphics2D pG) {
        final Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(125, 125, 50, 50);
        pG.fill(circle);
        pG.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        pG.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override public void paint(final Graphics pG) {
        super.paint(pG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, Jay! Versions 2 to 4 work well. Version 1 still gave blank canvas. Took me a while to figure it out, but eventually I got it working. Turns out I should have used overridden update() instead of paint(). So here is the code that puts ellipses with coordinates and height width chosen by input into the yellow canvas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Draws simple shapes
 */
public class SimpleDraw5 {

private Frame frame;
private static MyCanvas canvas;
private static Graphics graphics;
private Panel panel;
Ellipse2D.Double circle;

/**
 * Draws blue ellipses on yellow canvas
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDraw5 draw = new SimpleDraw5();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    draw.addShapes();
    int test;
    boolean exit = false;
    while (exit == false){
        System.out.println("Draw another?");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to keep drawing, 2 to close window "
                + "3 to stop but keep window open>");
        test = scan.nextInt();
        if(test == 1){
            draw.addShapes();
        }
        else if (test == 2)
            System.exit(0);
        else
            exit = true;
    }

}//end main

/**
 * Constructor
 * Creates canvas and frame
 */
public SimpleDraw5() {
    frame = new Frame("Draw picture");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
        } } );
    panel = new Panel();
    frame.add(panel);
    canvas = new MyCanvas();
    panel.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public void addShapes(){
    canvas.update(canvas.getGraphics());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Returns circle set with paramenters
 * @param x - X coordinate
 * @param y - Y coordinate
 * @param height
 * @param width
 * @return - object of class Ellipse2D.Double
 */
public static Ellipse2D.Double getCircle(int x, int y, int height, int width){
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,height, width);
    return circle;
}//end method

/**
 * Returns "default" circle
 * @return - object of class Ellipse2D.Double
 */
public static Ellipse2D.Double getCircle(){
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,50, 50);
    return circle;
}//end method

/**
 * Inner class- defines canvas
 *
 */
class MyCanvas extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    /**
     * Constructor. Sets canvas size and colors
     */
    public MyCanvas(){
        setSize(250, 250);
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    }//end


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.awt.Canvas#paint(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }//end method


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.awt.Canvas#update(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    public void update(Graphics g){
        g = this.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter x");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y");
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter w");
        int w = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter h");
        int h = scan.nextInt();
        Ellipse2D.Double circle = getCircle(x,y,w,h);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(circle);
        ((Graphics2D) g).draw(circle);
        graphics = g;
    }//end method   
}//end inner class
}//end class
```