# How to create independent JPanel-Layers within JFrame and repaint each indiviually

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jlayeredpane

I'm searching for a way to paint several `JComponents` above each other (overlap) and still being able to individually access and alter them.

E.g. paint three `JPanels` with transparent backgrounds - each containing a circle, a rectangle or a line. 
Afterwards, I'd like to change the appearance of the circle. The other two should not be repainted (similarly to layers in Photoshop).

My current project has a `Jpanel` with thousands of lines and I need to change a rectangle in the back on mouseover if I redraw the complete `Jpanel` each time it is very laggy.

Is there a decent way to accomplish that? Thank you already for your ideas!

Comment: A better way would be to have one JPanel and several BufferedImages as your layers.  Paint each BufferedImage in order, taking care not to paint the transparent areas.  You do have to clear and repaint the entire drawing area for each frame of the animation.  Also, your drawing panel paintComponent method should just paint.  No calculations.  Nothing else but Graphics2D methods.  A final alternative would be to model your geometric figures, and draw the figures from the model.

Comment: Take a look at my [Moving Eyes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981403/bufferedimage-not-being-cleared-before-each-rendering/35002727#35002727) answer to see how to set up a drawing panel in Swing.

Comment: That sounds like it could solve my problem! BufferedImages as layers - I'll try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change a rectangle in the back

You can invoke:

```
panel.repaint(rectangle); // or 
panel.repaint(x, y, width, height);
```

to specify the Rectangular area to be repainted.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But in my scenario all jpanels are laying directly above each other - so they have the same bounding boxes. I.e. repainting the rectangle leads to the repaint of all other layers completely. Basically the rectangle is equivalent to a background.

Comment: That is correct. Swing will look at the component you want to repaint and look at all its parents until it finds a component with an opaque background. Then it paints the background and all the child components at that location. This is to make sure the area is painted completely free of artifacts. My suggestion was not to paint the rectangle of the entire panel, but only a subset of the panel that changed. So when you change the circle you only repaint the area fully contained by the circle.

Comment: @MatthiasK, Repainting panels containing a circle a rectangle and a line is not an issue. I have painted hundreds of objects at one time without a problem. You must have some other painting issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! In my project I'm actually painting huge amounts (>10000) of paths (lines with more than 100 edges) - so repaint is not an option. Partial repaint is also hard, as the lines are all over the place and only spare tiny spots in between.. what i would need is some kind of transparent layers, which you draw once and show and hide whenever you like - without any calculation effort... 
Guess the hint from Gilbert Le Blanc could be the right way - using Buffered Images - I'll definitely take a look at that!

Answer (score 0):

It worked quite fine - here is my code if anyone else has a similar problem!
the first image can be stored and displayed later on (buff) 
Make sure to generate new BufferedImage (here canvas) when displaying again, as the transperency is lost otherways. Thanks to Gilbert Le Blanc

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
    //Create image:
    BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(mywidth, myheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    //write to image:
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) buff.getGraphics();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,(float) 0.01f));
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.draw(xxxRectanglewhatever);

    //then - later draw image again
    BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(mywidth, myheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    canvas.getGraphics().drawImage(buff, 0, 0, null);
    ((Graphics2D) g1).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g1.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.flush();
}
```